# How to show local devices in flutter (AVD)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to discover the deices which are running a specified service exposed to the local network, but I don't know how to. For ex. I want to show networks from avahi tool.

Is there any way to achieve this in Flutter ? (with full code)

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've checked pub.dev, but seems there is something specially for Avahi:

https://pub.dev/packages/avahi

and for query on multicast services :

https://pub.dev/packages/multicast_dns